# React web app experiencing severe lag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conways-game-of-life

I have an app in React which simulates Conway's Game of Life. It consists of a simple 2D array which updates every 0.01 seconds with new elements as specified by a setInterval() function. However, after running smoothly for the first 5 seconds it slows down considerably until it is updating every 0.5 seconds or so. I've been at a loss when trying to find what is causing the app to slow down so heavily.

Here is the entire grid component which renders the 2D array:

```
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Button = require('react-bootstrap').Button;
var Row = require('react-bootstrap').Row;
var Col = require('react-bootstrap').Col;
var FontAwesome = require('react-fontawesome');

// components
var Cell = require('./Cell.jsx');

var Grid = createReactClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      matrix: [],
      generations: 0,
      neighborCells: [[0, 1], [1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, -1], [1, 1], [-1, 1], [1, -1]]
    };
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.freshGrid();
  },

  freshGrid: function() {
    var matrix = [];
    var dim = this.props.dim;

    var Cell = function() {
      this.neighborsCount = 0;
      this.isAlive = false;
    }

    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
      var row = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        counter++;
        var cell = new Cell();
        row.push(cell);

        if (counter%2 == 0) {
          cell.isAlive = true;
        }
      }
      matrix.push(row);
    }

    this.setState({matrix: matrix}, function() {
      this.createGrid();
    });
  },

  createGrid: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(function() {
      this.countNeighbours();
      this.updateCells();
      this.forceUpdate();
      this.clearNeighborsCount();
    }.bind(this), 10);
  },

  countNeighbours: function() {
    var dim = this.props.dim;

    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        this.countNeighboursCell(i, j);
      }
    }
  },

  countNeighboursCell: function(row, col) {
    var neighborCells = this.state.neighborCells;
    var cell = this.state.matrix[row][col];

    for (var i = 0; i < neighborCells.length; i++) {
      var neighborPos = neighborCells[i];
      var x = row + neighborPos[0];
      var y = col + neighborPos[1];

      if (this.isWithinGrid(x, y)) {
        var neighbor = this.state.matrix[x][y];
        if (neighbor.isAlive) {
          cell.neighborsCount++;
        }
      }
    }
  },

  isWithinGrid: function(row, col) {
    var dim = this.props.dim;

    if (row >= 0 && col >= 0 && row < dim && col < dim) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },

  updateCells: function() {
    var dim = this.props.dim;

    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        var currentCell = this.state.matrix[i][j];

        if (currentCell.isAlive && (currentCell.neighborsCount == 2 || currentCell.neighborsCount == 3)) {
          currentCell.isAlive = true;
        } else if (!currentCell.isAlive && currentCell.neighborsCount == 3) {
          currentCell.isAlive = true;
        } else {
          currentCell.isAlive = false;
        }
      }
    }
  },

  clearNeighborsCount: function() {
    var dim = this.props.dim;

    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        this.state.matrix[i][j].neighborsCount = 0;
      }
    }
  },

  togglePause: function(e) {
    if (e.target.innerHTML === 'Pause') {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      e.target.innerHTML = 'Play';
    } else {
      e.target.innerHTML = 'Pause';
      this.createGrid();
    }
  },

  reset: function() {
    this.freshGrid();
  },

  render: function() {
    var dim = this.props.dim;

    var cells = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
      var row = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        row.push(<Cell key={i+j} row={i} col={j} dim={10} isAlive={this.state.matrix[i][j].isAlive} />)
      }
      cells.push(row);
    };

    var gridStyle = {
            width: this.props.dim * 10,
            height: this.props.dim * 10,
            background: "#FAFAFA",
            margin: "0 auto",
            WebKitBoxShadow: "0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            MozBoxShadow: "0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            boxShadow: "0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
        };

    return (
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} md={2}>
          <Button onClick={this.togglePause} bsStyle="warning">Pause</Button>
          {/* <Button onClick={this.reset} bsStyle="danger">Reset</Button> */}
        </Col>

        <Col xs={12} md={10}>
          <div style={gridStyle}>
            {cells}
          </div>
        </Col>
    </Row>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Grid;
```

As you can see in the createGrid() function we update the grid every 0.01 seconds with new elements. However, over time it slows up considerably. I'm trying to find what is causing it to lag so heavily. It happens on all browsers and also on mobile.

EDIT:

As requested, here is Cell.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var Cell = createReactClass({

  render: function() {
    var dim = this.props.dim;

    var cellStyle = {
            width: dim,
            height: dim,
            dislay: "inline-block",
            float: "left",
            border: "1px solid #000",
            background: this.props.isAlive ? "#FFF" : "#151515"
        };

    return(
      <div className="cell" onClick={this.clicked} style={cellStyle}></div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Cell;
```

EDIT 2:

```
You can render the grid with this App component

var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

// components
var Grid = require('./Grid.jsx');

var App = createReactClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <Grid dim={51}/>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Comment: Can I ask why are you running `this.forceUpdate();`? I might be missing something but you are doing lots of calculations in your interval but I couldn't see how and where you are using those calculations.

Comment: `Cell.jsx` please.

Comment: Have you tried running profiler ? Google Chrome - F12 - Performance tab

Comment: What size of grid are you testing ? Have you tried removing box-shadow css ?

Comment: Why are you checking .isAlive in .render ? you are mixing up view and model. `row.push(<Cell key={i+j} row={i} col={j} dim={10} isAlive={this.state.matrix[i][j].isAlive} />)`

Comment: Here's a codesandbox for folks to try - https://codesandbox.io/s/qqrvk8rwwq

Comment: Unrelated: you have typo in Cell.jsx `display: inline-block`

Comment: @hazardous it does not render grid at all for me (Opera Android), does it work for you ?

Comment: The Grid is collapsed for me too :). Maybe op can create a codesandbox. I tried adding bootstrap.css as external dependencies as well, which fixed the button style, but grid is still collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Few tips based on the existing code -

1. Don't use a timer.
   Instead of a timer, you can render the matrix once, then in `componentDidUpdate`, call the function which updates the matrix. In this function, you will store the new matrix back in state using `setState`, which will trigger `render` for the new state. This will continue forever, but will not pile up multiple executions.
2. Use immutable state. The current code is directly referencing `state.matrix` and updating the `cells`. This will mutate state without re-rendering. You can either use Object.assign for this, or use ImmutableJS.
3. Restructure your code to do this in the following fashion -

   calculate matrix > render > repeat

   Write a function say `calculateMatrix` which takes current matrix and returns the next matrix. Write another function `updateMatrix` which invokes `calculateMatrix` on the current matrix and then invokes `setState` to store the new matrix into state. Invoke `updateMatrix` in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. This will kick off the calculate > render > repeat cycle ad infinitum.